# Mathematica calendar for 2023

Tags: plotting

[Here](https://github.com/rcorless/rcorless.github.io/blob/main/2022_Bohemian_Wall_CalendarA4MondayWeek.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1Z5QQIt5jEvtqzpG9sLrjVnHhpKYCyFug9-PlnayRmvsPtL2E55LnU3Cw) is
a Maple calendar for 2022 as an example. I am pretty sure there is a lot of nice Mathematica visualizations of deep math results which may be used for such a calendar for 2023.
I am not strong in that field and because of this reason I ask it at this forum.

[image]

Let us make better.

Comment: I suggest you have a read about what is on-topic here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and particularly what is off-topic   here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  I'm afraid you are asking an opinion/subjective open ended question, and not a programming question. Consequently, I'm voting to close this question. You can [edit] your question to prevent or revert closure.

Comment: @rhermans: Thank you for your personal opinion.  I  disagree with you.  I think this is a good idea. Few years ago I was given as a gift  such a calendar from  the AMS.

Comment: @rhermans:  How about [that question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273495/working-with-country-flags-in-mathematica)? There are many questions of such type in this forum.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Calendar#Mathematica/Wolfram_Language

Comment: Right. We each have votes to use according to our judgment. It takes more than one vote to close. We don't need to argue with people about their votes.

Comment: @lericr: Sorry, but your example is not better than quoted by me.

Comment: omg. I think you're taking me a bit too seriously.

Comment: I guess the meta point here is that you can create structures however you want, even a text-only calendar. Your question is just an open-ended challenge-ish type of question with no specific purpose or coding question. You might as well ask whether Mathematica can be used to show a map of the galaxy or a representation of a clade for studying evolution or whtever.

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic on the main site, but it's also fun to do and good for community building on this site. I suggest migrating to meta, and discussing it in chat. I'm sure many people would enjoy contributing. @rhermans It could be a way to encourage more participation in chat / meta.

Answer (score 3):

I guess a proper presentation would require a bit more time. Here I have a fake calendar with essential structure. `35` is the total number of slots for dates, 31 is the number of days in this fake `Month`, `5` is the offset for the first day (Sunday being 0). The dates fold up as shown on to the first row as a bonus feature.

```
Prepend[
  Prepend[
   Partition[
    RotateRight[
     PadRight[Range[31], 35, ""], 5]
    , 7, 7],
   {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"}]
  , {"Month", SpanFromLeft}] // Grid
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

```
Clear[mCal]
mCal[d_DateObject, lang_String : "English"] := 
 Module[{day, month, year, firstDay, monthNames, dayNames, dayRules, 
   daysInMonth, calM, todayPos},
  
  day = If[MissingQ[d["Day"]], "", d["Day"]];
  month = d["Month"];
  year = If[MissingQ[d["Year"]], Today["Year"], d["Year"]];
  
  daysInMonth = {31, If[LeapYearQ[{year}], 29, 28], 31, 30, 31, 30, 
    31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
  monthNames = {
    "January", "February", "March", "April"
    , "May", "June", "July", "August"
    , "September", "October", "November", "December"};
  dayNames = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
  dayRules = {Monday -> 1, Tuesday -> 2, Wednesday -> 3, 
    Thursday -> 4, Friday -> 5, Saturday -> 6, Sunday -> 0};
  
  firstDay = (DateObject[{year, month, 1}]["DayName"] /. dayRules);
  
  calM = Partition[
    RotateRight[
     PadRight[Range[daysInMonth[[month]]], 35, ""], firstDay]
    , 7, 7];
  
  todayPos = If[day == "", {0, 0}, First@Position[calM, day] + {2, 0}];
  
  Prepend[
    Prepend[calM, Style[#, 14] & /@ dayNames]
    , {Style[monthNames[[month]] <> " " <> ToString@year, 20
      , FontFamily ->
       "Old English Text MT"
      ], SpanFromLeft}] // Grid[#
     , Spacings -> {0.4, 0.8}
     (*,Frame\[Rule]All*)
     , Background -> {None, None
       , {todayPos -> GrayLevel[0.85]}
       }
     , Alignment -> {Center, Center}
     , Dividers -> {{False}, {False, True, True, {False}}}
     , ItemSize -> {2, {2.5, 2, {1.2}}}
     , ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {
        {{2, -1}, {1, 1}} -> Red
        , {{2, -1}, {6, 6}} -> Darker@Darker@Green
        , {{2, -1}, {7, 7}} -> Blue}
       }
     ] &
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

If a date is provided it is highlighted. English is the default (only) language available.

```
d1 = DateObject[{2022, 11}];
d2 = DateObject[Today]
mCal /@ {d1, d2}
```

---

**Calendar 2023**

```
cal2023 = Grid[
   Partition[#, 3] &@
    (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> {{2, 4}, {3, 3}}] & /@
      mCal /@ (DateObject[{2023, #}] & /@ Range[12])
     ), Spacings -> {0.2, 0.2}
   ];
Export["C:/cal2023.pdf", cal2023]
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for your constructive reply, My question need not be answered in short time: we have at least 44 days to this end.

Comment: This is a usual calendar done with Mathematica. The beauty and content of calendars consist in commented illustrations as in  the linked Maple calendar. Sorry, you answered the suggestion of @lericr,  not my question. I will be waiting for a rich-in-content calendars.

Comment: Also the previous and next months are not displayed so this is not practical. BTW, did you look in the Maple one? Or only in https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Calendar#Mathematica/Wolfram_Language?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I downloaded it. It is nice and I wouldn't know how to generate similar pictures to put in there. If the question is still open I might add next and previous months. For that, I will have to make a miniaturized version since font sizes are hardcoded.

Comment: The pictures in the Maple one are  commented visualizations of math results done with Maple. The question  is still open as yet. Such calendars are business cards of organizations.